# passing multi valued parameter to sub report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, subreport

I have built a report which lists all the loans that are available for a specified date range(below is the screen shot of the report).There are a number of filters and data logic involved in pulling this report.The numbers high-lighted in yellow are the total no of loans in each bucket.When the user clicks on the totals I need to open a sub report with all loans falling in that bucket.I have created a sub report which accepts loan numbers as a parameter and set it to allow multiple values. Set the text box properties on the main report to go to the subreport when clicked on the totals.But I am unaware of how to pass multiple loan numbers from the main report to sub report. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

What I am currently doing is passing required filters/details to the sub report , so that it can reevaluate. Reevaluating the report takes a lot of of time as there are many condition that need to be evaluated. It would be quicker if I could send the list of loan numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pass a list, you'll need to pass in enough detail so your subreport can reevaluate and come back with the same set of loans.

This might be a little simplistic but base on your screen show you would pass in the Date Range column value. I'll assume for now (as I have no more information on your data) that the column is just a text column as it appears above.

So you sub-report would accept a `daterange` parameter and you would pass this as `=Fields!DateRange.Value`. The subreport would then do something like..

`SELECT * FROM myLoansTable WHERE DateRange = @daterange`

If there are more parameters set in the main report, you may need to pass those too so your subreport gives the same set of loans as displayed in the main report.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What I am currently doing is the same, passing details to the sub report , so that it can reevaluate. Reevaluating the report takes a lot of of time as there are many condition that need to be evaluated. It would be quicker if I could send the list of loan numbers.